# Error launching app : Default activity not found - One out of two times

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-manifest

I am using Android Studio.
When I launch my app, I get the error `Default activity not found`.
I know the `Sync Project with Gradle Files` method, it works, but I need to use it each time I want to launch my app.

I also tried `Invalidate Cache and Restart`, but it did not solve anything.

Here is a part of my `AndroidManifest.xml` :

```
<activity android:name="com.discodery.android.discoderyapp.SplashActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Is there a way to definitively solve this problem ?

I also have weird errors (that does not cancel build) like this one :

```
companion object {
    fun getStartIntent(context: Context) : Intent = Intent(context, MessageSentActivity::class.java)
}
```

Well in this example, the `java` word at the end of the line is red, and say `Unresolved reference : java`.

I guess my editor is broken, but I uninstalled it this afternoon and it kept giving me these errors.

Thanks.

Comment: Does SplashActivity extend Activity?

Comment: @JoshuaBest It extends `AppCompatActivity()`

Comment: Does your IDE behave this way for other projects?

Comment: @Elynad very stange, have you tried using androidx whilst using kotlin?

Comment: @TaslimOseni yes, it does

Comment: @JoshuaBest No, I don't know this. Is this an implementation I should add in my gradle file ?

Comment: The problem is definitely with your IDE then.

Comment: @TaslimOseni Sure, but how to fix it ? Even after an uninstall / reinstall it kept bugging.
Might it be caused by the last version of Android Studio ?

Comment: I think you should update your plugin like kotlin and build tools in Project build.gradle. might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved !
Here is what I did :

- Uninstalled Android Studio, (ticked the box "Remove user data")
- Reinstalled it
- Updated `ext.kotlin_version` to `1.3.21` as suggested dastan
- Removed `app/build` directory
- Clean project
- Rebuild project

I think it was the kotlin version that was threwing me this exception. Thanks dastan for your answer !